# Deleting DataGridView rows

Tags: c#

When I am trying to Delete all rows in DataGridView

I got this exception

> Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the
>     SetCurrentCellAddressCore Function

Notes :

I tryed this

```
datagridview1.Rows.Clear();
```

and this

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item datagridview1.Rows)
{
    datagridview1.Rows.Remove(item);
}
```

and this

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item datagridview1.Rows)
{
    datagridview1.Rows.RemoveAt(item.index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `datagridview1.EndEdit();` before deleting rows.
See also: [Why is my bound DataGridView throwing an “Operation not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function” error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114668/why-is-my-bound-datagridview-throwing-an-operation-not-valid-because-it-results)

**EDIT:** Please note that you cannot delete rows in the following event handlers:

- CellEnter
- CellLeave
- CellValidating
- CellValidated
- RowEnter
- RowLeave
- RowValidated
- RowValidating

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.remove%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Notes : my code is written into the event datagridView_CellEndEdit so i can't delete the row which contains the current cell

Answer (score 0):

Clear the datasource that the DataGridView is bound to.

```
datasource.Clear()
```