# How to evade reentrant call to setCurrentCellAddressCore?

Tags: c#, datagridview, invalidoperationexception

I have a function that is called from cell_endedit. It moves a dataGridViewRow inside a dataGridView:

```
private void moveRowTo(DataGridView table, int oldIndex, int newIndex)
{
    if (newIndex < oldIndex)
    {
        oldIndex += 1;
    }
    else if (newIndex == oldIndex)
    {
        return;
    }
    table.Rows.Insert(newIndex, 1);
    DataGridViewRow row = table.Rows[newIndex];
    DataGridViewCell cell0 = table.Rows[oldIndex].Cells[0];
    DataGridViewCell cell1 = table.Rows[oldIndex].Cells[1];
    row.Cells[0].Value = cell0.Value;
    row.Cells[1].Value = cell1.Value;
    table.Rows[oldIndex].Visible = false;
    table.Rows.RemoveAt(oldIndex);
    table.Rows[oldIndex].Selected = false;
    table.Rows[newIndex].Selected = true;
}
```

at row table.Rows.Insert(newIndex, 1) i get the following error:

> Unhandled exception of type "System.InvalidOperationException" in
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional data: Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function.

It happens when I click another cell in process of editing current cell.
How do i evade such error and have my row inserted correctly?

Comment: I get the same error in a DataGridView with ReadOnly = True and FullRowSelect mode (.NET 4.6.2 Windows Forms, VS2019)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This error is caused by

> Any operation that results in the active cell being changed while the DataGridView is still using it

As the accepted answer [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5115139/815938).

The fix (I have verified): use `BeginInvoke` to call `moveRowTo`.

```
private void dataGridView2_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
            moveRowTo(dataGridView2, 0, 1);
        }));
}
```

`BeginInvoke` is an asynchronous call, so `dataGridView2_CellEndEdit` returns immediately, and the `moveRowTo` method is executed after that, at that time `dataGridView2` is no longer using the currently active cell.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (
    (datagridview.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex != datagridview.CurrentCell.RowIndex) ||
    (datagridview.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex!= datagridview.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex)
   ) { return; }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.