# Refresh DataGridView on CellEndEdit

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have `DataGridView` that need to refreshed everytime the cell edited. It is in `CellEndEdit` event :

```
    private void gridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //some code for updating to database here
        Grid_Load();
    }
```

`Grid_Load(code)` has normal refresh task :

```
    public void Grid_Load(string code)
    {
        try
        {
            String sqlString = "SELECT e.room, e.room, c.code, c.[weight], c.[date], c.sender, c.receiver, c.container, c.seal, c.note " +
                "FROM loadingPlan a INNER JOIN loadingPlanDetail b " +
                "ON a.ID = b.loadingID INNER JOIN containerTransaction c " +
                "ON b.transactionCode = c.code LEFT JOIN stowage d " +
                "ON a.code = d.loadingCode LEFT JOIN stowageDetail e " +
                "ON b.transactionCode = e.transactionCode " +
                "WHERE a.code = @code " +
                "AND d.ID = @id " +
                "ORDER BY c.[weight] ASC ";

            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlString, connString))
            {
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@code", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = code;
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = this.id;

                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    da.Fill(ds, "data");

                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt = ds.Tables["data"];

                    gridView.DataSource = dt;

                    gridView.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
                    gridView.Columns[0].Visible = false;
                    gridView.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Room";
                    gridView.Columns["code"].HeaderText = "No. Transaksi";
                    gridView.Columns["code"].ReadOnly = true;
                    gridView.Columns["weight"].HeaderText = "Berat";
                    gridView.Columns["weight"].ReadOnly = true;
                    gridView.Columns["date"].HeaderText = "Tanggal";
                    gridView.Columns["date"].ReadOnly = true;
                    gridView.Columns["sender"].HeaderText = "Pengirim";
                    gridView.Columns["sender"].ReadOnly = true;
                    gridView.Columns["receiver"].HeaderText = "Penerima";
                    gridView.Columns["receiver"].ReadOnly = true;
                    gridView.Columns["container"].HeaderText = "No. Kontainer";
                    gridView.Columns["container"].ReadOnly = true;
                    gridView.Columns["seal"].HeaderText = "No. Seal";
                    gridView.Columns["seal"].ReadOnly = true;
                    gridView.Columns["note"].HeaderText = "Keterangan";
                    gridView.Columns["note"].ReadOnly = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Everything works perfectly but something weird exception when I click another cell while editing a cell.

> Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the
>   SetCurentCellAddressCore function

This error just thrown when I do click while editing. Arrow, Enter is works perfectly.

Comment: Maybe this post wil help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522927/how-to-evade-reentrant-call-to-setcurrentcelladdresscore

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette : thank you very much, can you please help me to mark as duplicate