# Can't change cell type at location where column and row are same

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Col1");
    dt.Columns.Add("Col2);

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(new string[] { j.ToString(), "aaa"});
    }

     dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Here I have created one datatable and bind it to data grid view. I want update column = 1 and row= 1 cell as a combobox cell when it clicked
so i used following events.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.RowIndex == 1)
    {
        object value = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
        ComboBoxCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
        ComboBoxCell.Items.AddRange(Values);
        this.dataGridView1[1, 1] = ComboBoxCell;
        this.dataGridView1[1, 1].Value = Values[0];
        TextBoxCell = null;
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.RowIndex == 1)
    {
        TextBoxCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
        this.dataGridView1[1, 1] = TextBoxCell;
        ComboBoxCell = null;
    }
}
```

but here in cell_leave event it raised exceptions

> "Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the
>   SetCurrentCellAddressCore function"

Please help me to resolve this.

I tried to add combo box on column=1 row = 2 then its working fine
but only when there is a same column and same row problem occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the CellMouseLeave event.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.RowIndex == 1)
    {
        DataGridViewTextBoxCell TextBoxCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
        this.dataGridView1[1, 1] = TextBoxCell;
    }
}
```

I tried above code it's working fine.

And i would also like to suggest you to read following answer.

[Why is my bound DataGridView throwing an "Operation not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114668/why-is-my-bound-datagridview-throwing-an-operation-not-valid-because-it-results)

It is not exactly working as CellLeave event but it may help you to find some solution.