# c# winforms datagridview issue when adding programmatically a row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm stuck on the following issue :

the datagridview i implement must always had an empty row,
so i use a BindingList as DataSource

but when the cells are programmatically filled, no row is added,

i can add a row by adding an item to my BindingList, but, and this very strange i can't adding an item to the BindingList if i test the position of the currentCell :

for example, this code is Ok,

```cs
public class MyObject: IMyObject
{
    public BindingList<MyItem> MyCollectionToDisplay{ get; set; }
    public void OneMoreLine()
    {
        MyItem myNewItem = new MyItem();
        this.MyCollectionToDisplay.Add(myNewItem);
    }
}
```

```cs
MydataGridView.DataSource = this.MyObject.MyCollectionToDisplay;
MydataGridView.CellLeave += MydataGridView_CellLeave;

private void MydataGridView_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   {
        this.MyObject.OneMoreLine();
   }
```

and this one is not Ok :

```cs
MydataGridView.DataSource = this.MyObject.MyCollectionToDisplay;
MydataGridView.CellLeave += MydataGridView_CellLeave;

private void MydataGridView_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
       var rowNumberOfTheCell = MydataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Index;
       var totalOfRows = MydataGridView.Rows.Count;
       if (rowNumberOfTheCell == totalOfRows - 1)
       {
            this.MyObject.OneMoreLine();
       }
   }
```

i've got the following exception :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>   Additional Information: The operation is not valid because of the current state of the object.

________________EDIT______________

Ok, i got it,

According to this thread : [Why is my bound DataGridView throwing an "Operation not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114668/why-is-my-bound-datagridview-throwing-an-operation-not-valid-because-it-results)

I cannot modified the DataSource while a cell edit the DataSource,

So i replace the CellLeave event by a MouseDown event :

```cs
MydataGridView.DataSource = this.MyObject.MyCollectionToDisplay;
MydataGridView.CellLeave += MydataGridView_CellLeave;

private void MydataGridView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            var rowIndex = this.MydataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;

            var totalOfRows = this.MydataGridView.Rows.Count;
            if (rowIndex == totalOfRows - 1)
            {
                this.MyObject.OneMoreLine();
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: You don't need to do anything in a cell leave. As soon as you start writing something in the last row of `DataGridView`, a new record will be added to the end of the rows list.

Comment: @ Reza Aghaei; yes if i manually writing something in the last, a new row is automatically added. But if i programmatically writing (i do some treatment on the cellLeave event, which add contents in the last row's cells) in the last row, no new row is added...

Comment: I am guessing the issue could be from the “default” setting for the `BindingList<T>`.The default setting for the `BindingList<T>.AllowNew` is FALSE... adding the line `MyCollectionToDisplay.AllowNew = true;` after initialization, should display the new row in the grid. NOTE: since the grid is adding a NEW row, it needs to know how to create a new `MyItem` object, therefore the Class `MyItem` MUST have a blank constructor or the code will crash when trying to create a new empty `MyItem` cell. Just a thought.